# KDE Plasma 5 - Switch windows of an application

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, plasma, plasma5

In GNOME 3.28.2, there's a keyboard shortcut option for "Switch windows of an application"

[image: Switch windows of an application]

Is there a way to do this in Plasma 5.18 LTS?

I would like application windows to be grouped such that Alt+Tab moves to a group, then Super+Tab toggles the active window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only test this on KDE Plasma 5.20, but I think it has not significantly changed in a while.

In "System Settings" > "Windows Management" > "Task Switcher" you should be able to:

- In the "Current application" section, set the shortcut keys for iterating over the windows belonging to the active application.
- Tick the "Only one window per application" checkbox to instruct the task switcher to "group" windows by the application they belong to and iterate over groups.